# MEF is no longer seeing one of my classes

Tags: c#, mef

I have this class:

```
[Export(typeof(IUtility))]
public class DataExporter : IUtility
{
    private int maxRows = int.MaxValue;
    private int sampleRate = 1;
    // etc
}
```

and I'm importing it in MEF like so:

```
[ImportMany]
public ISet<IUtility> Utilities { get; set; } = new HashSet<IUtility>();

private void Run(params string[] args)
{
    // find all commands that are defined in this assembly
    var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
    catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly));
    // TODO: figure out why loading assemblies from the executable's folder is crashing
    //catalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(Program).Assembly.Location)));
    container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.ComposeParts(this);
    // etc
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Instance.Run(args);
}
```

This was working the other day, but as of today, my `DataExporter` class is not being imported into the utilities collection. All my other utility classes are, though - what's wrong with this one?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had a build configuration selected that excluded the project containing my class. I had these set up to save time on builds (building only the projects I need at any given time).